Another boring relay board with ESP32
After years of breadbord and relay boards, I would like to try to build a my own relay board, the relay side schema is the follow:

Figure 1.
I went for the 2N2222 but the BC337 is a good candidate also?
The RELAY_CMD come from an ESP32.
Can R16 be 470 ohm? For a switching purpose and long life, is better to go in saturation?
Can this schema consider to be good and oriented to a long life duration? I was thinking to put a optocoupler between 3,3V and 12V but the ground is common, so I don't think have much sense.
This board will be used to handle an observatory and will be marked as open hardware, what I'm trying to get is an easy assembly way (no SDM) and a long life.
Being my first PCB development I don't know how place object in the right way:

Figure 2.
I got 10 relays, I have no dimensional problem but I don't want a board like a stadium, I was thinking about this way to place objects to save space but at the same time to help the building, I want to vertical resistor, LED centered with relay, is a good compromise? I'm afraid cause, in one side I put everything in a square of 15mmx15mm but what when I will solder them?
I also got these two solutions in mind:

Figure 3.

If board space is tight, then why pick this kind of "Arduino relay"? Do you really need 10A current or whatever that one is rated for?

Also if switching AC place the relay contacts as close to the connector as possible.

@Lundin 10A probably not, But 5A yes, I choose this relay cause I got some working since years, using some relay boards I got issue with the coils.
The probability to switch AC is high, I was thinking about it in the first pcb layout, in the send one I was wondering that was not a problem, but ok, I will move led in the back of realy

The PWB is important, but the higher-level system wiring is important also. Try to keep the relay coil currents away from the logic. When you have a separate supply (12V) for the relay coil, this should be easy.

Not to rock the boat, but I have seen engineers use Darlington Transistors to overcome  the current problems @Transistor pointed out in their answer. I have also seen where higher voltage (12 Volt coils) relays chosen over lower voltage (5 Volt coils) relays. Noise immunity was the reason given.

@st2000, how would the double PN base junctions of a Darlington work with a 3.3 V GPIO. It should be OK but there isn't a lot of headroom. I've never had to try it.

3.3V - 2* 0.7V = 1.9V That doesn't sound too bad. But I don't know what the minimum voltage of a ESP32 Hi output is though. Also, for more ideas, you might want to look at this question asked 7+ years ago here on electrical engineering stack exchange.

Figure 2

This looks good. You have mains on the top edge of the PCB and control voltage on the bottom edge.
I would give extra clearance between the relay common (live) and the LED.
The red trace between R16 and Q8 is too close to pin 3 on Q8. You have plenty of space!

Figure 3

Not so good!
You have crossover between the mains circuit and the control circuit. The LEDs and resistors are much too close to the mains traces. Move them back to the lower edge of the board.

In general, there should be clear "no-man's land" with no copper between the two isolated circuits. In some designs they cut slots in the PCB to eliminate any chance of creepage across the surface.

R16
To switch a transistor into saturation the general "rule of thumb" is that you should give it 10 × the base current that is suggested by the hfe calculation. For a 2N2222 you could assume hfe = 100.
The Finder 36.11 12 V coil has a resistance of 400 Ω so you want a collector current of \$ I = \frac VR = \frac {12}{400} = 30\ \text{mA} \$. This suggests a base current of 0.3 mA but applying our overdrive factor of 10 we get 3 mA base current.
If you're driving from a 3.3 V GPIO into 0.7 V at the base you'll have 2.4 V dropped across the resistor so \$ R = \frac VI = \frac {2.4}{0.003} = 800 \ \Omega \$. Your suggestion of 470 Ω would work fine but probably make the GPIO work a bit harder than necessary and consume additional power.

Thanks for the editing and for the response, I will go with the figure 2 layout considering also the probability of handling AC devices.
As I asked can you help me in the R16 value question?

Cutting up slots between the traces is common design indeed, at least in case of VAC. It doesn't really cost anything extra so why not use it.

See the update.


I have no dimensional problem but I don't want a board like a stadium

Then you can use SMD components for everything except connector and relay. Here's an example from a board I did last month:

If the relay switches mains voltage, or any kind of high voltage, then you need good separation between that and your low voltage traces. ESP32 is a bit of a special case, as it uses WiFi, which is isolated... as long as no-one uses the USB programming port, or puts a finger on the RESET button.
If humidity or pollution is expected, it's also possible to mill a slot between the low and high voltage sides of the relay (see above pic).
If you absolutely want the LED next to th connectors, then it would be a problem of course. The usual solutions are "light pipes", a fancy name for bits of transparent plastic than guide the light from the LEDs where you want it without breaking isolation.
So your first PCB example is good, but the other ones are not.
Most modern LEDs are too bright at 10mA so R15 could be higher.
If you intend to switch nasty inductive loads, some extra precautions may be needed to both preserve the life of the contacts and prevent arc EMI from causing reboots.
Also I like Wago 256-401. No need to crimp.


Yes, probably in the future I will move to sdm, but I would like that everyone can be able to make the board, and not everyone is good to weld smd, me included. Finally I understad why olso in some Board there's that cut near the common pin of the relay, thank you! I used the phonix cause in case of problem you can disconnect it without moving wires, but olso yours can be a nice solution. I'm with you for the led, sincerly I like old style low right led, expecially in an observatory where less light is present and better is
